# Python curses getmaxyx not refreshed with ipython debugger tracer

Tags: python, ipython, python-curses

I am working on a project using curses in Python.

I use `stdscr.getmaxyx()` in a `while True` loop to get the current terminal window size, in order to display text at the center of the terminal window.

The code below works as expected: when you run it and resize the terminal, the text stays at the center of the window and displays the current terminal size.

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer
# debug_here = Tracer()


def main(stdscr):
    inp = 'Initial'
    while True:
        y, x = stdscr.getmaxyx()
        curses.curs_set(0)
        stdscr.clear()
        stdscr.refresh()
        stdscr.addstr(int(y/2), int(x/2), '{}x{}'.format(y, x))
        stdscr.addstr(int(y/2)+1, int(x/2), inp)
        try:
            inp = stdscr.getkey()
        except curses.error:
            inp = '...'


wrapper(main)
```

When I uncomment line 4 (`debug_here = Tracer()`), the code still runs but the terminal size is not updated when I resize it, and so the text does not always display in the center.

Do you know if this behavior is expected, and the reason for this to occur?